# PriorityQueue - в классе объявлены избыточные конструкторы?

Tags: java, коллекции, очередь

В классе `PriorityQueue` определен конструктор, который принимает аргументом `Collection`. В этом конструкторе имеется проверка аргумента на соответствие типам`SortedSet` и `PriorityQueue`:

```
public PriorityQueue(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    if (c instanceof SortedSet<?>) {
        SortedSet<? extends E> ss = (SortedSet<? extends E>) c;
        this.comparator = (Comparator<? super E>) ss.comparator();
        initElementsFromCollection(ss);
    }
    else if (c instanceof PriorityQueue<?>) {
        PriorityQueue<? extends E> pq = (PriorityQueue<? extends E>) c;
        this.comparator = (Comparator<? super E>) pq.comparator();
        initFromPriorityQueue(pq);
    }
    else {
        this.comparator = null;
        initFromCollection(c);
    }
}
```

С какой целью тогда разработчики класса добавили отдельные конструкторы, принимающие в аргументе `SortedSet`:

```
public PriorityQueue(SortedSet<? extends E> c) {
    this.comparator = (Comparator<? super E>) c.comparator();
    initElementsFromCollection(c);
}
```

и `PriorityQueue`:

```
public PriorityQueue(PriorityQueue<? extends E> c) {
    this.comparator = (Comparator<? super E>) c.comparator();
    initFromPriorityQueue(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instanceof` - достаточно затратная операция. И если мы сразу присылаем `SortedSet` или `PriorityQueue`, то нет смысла тратить на это время. А вот если мы прислали `Collection`, то, какая конкретно пришла коллекция, никому не известно.

Comment: Не понял ответа. Если разработчики решили все-таки добавить конструктор, принимающий `SortedSet` и `PriorityQueue`, то зачем в конструкторе с `Collection` предварительно делать проверку на `SS` и `PQ`? Ведь если в аргументах передадут какой-либо из этих классов, то программа сразу пойдет в конструктор с соответствующим аргументом (overloading)

Comment: Не обязательно. Смотри, есть у тебя `SortedSet` (к примеру ss). Можешь ты по какой-то причине сделать `Collection c = ss` (например, передать его в метод, принимающий `Collection`)? Вполне. Так вот, в данном случае
`... new PriorityQueue(ss);...` пойдет именно в конструктор с `SortedSet`, а вот
`... new PriorityQueue(c);...` пойдет в конструктор с `Collection`